# Mongo query for embedded document with key other than a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo (3.6) collection that looks like this (the ISODates are set to various times, the actual times aren't important here):

```
{_id: 0}
{_id: 1, a: null}
{_id: 2, a: {}}
{_id: 3, a: {"0": ISODate("...")}}
{_id: 4, a: {"1625": ISODate("...")}}
{_id: 5, a: {"0": ISODate("..."), "1625": ISODate("...")}}
{_id: 6, a: {"7": ISODate("..."), "900": ISODate("...")}}
```

I want to query for documents where the `a` field (always an embedded document if present) contains at least one key that has a value other than "0". So in my example it would return documents 4, 5 and 6.

I know I can do this with a `$where` clause, but is there a way to do it without using `$where`?

Comment: If `a` is an object how can it be like this : `{"0", "1625": ISODate("...")}` ? where `0` stands on it's own without a value ?

Comment: @whoami oops nice catch, I put in a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
      { a: { $type: "object" } },
      { a: { $ne: {} } }, // This is optional but might improve performance by remove empty objects `{}` to next step.
      { $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: { $filter: { input: { $objectToArray: "$a" }, cond: { $ne: [ "$$this.k", "0" ] } } } }, 0 ] } }
    ]
  })
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Xge_U1NobR)

**Note :** You can try this query if you don't want to execute a function in `$where`, this query use `$expr` to execute aggregation expression with in query language.

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Wow that is impressive I didn't realise the aggregation pipeline could express this. I'm not worried about performance in my particular case, I just don't like using $where if I don't need to. So I'm hoping for a straight up query but if one doesn't emerge then I'll accept this answer as the best that can be done